# Counting the Number of Closed Binary Operations That Are Commutative

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I'm working my way through the Section 5.4 exercises for the Grimaldi textbook, and the book's answer to one of the exercises doesn't make any sense to me.  I was hoping someone could help me understand how it reaches its given answer.

Here's the problem: Let $|A| = 5$.  How many closed binary operations on $A$ are commutative?

The book gives the answer $5^{10}$, but that makes little sense to me.  When I do the problem, I get $5^{15}$.

Here's how I reach $5^{15}$. There are $5$ functions that have double pairs (i.e., $f(a,a),f(b,b),f(c,c),f(d,d),f(e,e)$), and each of those has $5$ possible answers.  Thus, there are $5^5$ potential arrangements for those $5$ inputs.  For the rest of the inputs (which should be only $20$, since $25-5=20$), each combination of inputs corresponds with another combination if the function is commutative (i.e., $f(a,b) = f(b,a)$).  So we only have to match half (i.e., $10$) of the remaining possible combinations with answers.  That leaves us with $5^{10}$ potential arrangements for the remaining $10$ possible inputs.  The total number of commutative operations should therefore be $5^{5} \times 5^{10} = 5^{15}$, not $5^{10}$.

Given this discrepancy, I thought I'd share my thoughts for scrutiny and see if I'm missing something. Any help or insight on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: I believe you're right, your reasoning looks perfectly good to me. Although I agree with your answer, I may also be making an oversight here, so let's see if anyone else has anything to say about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Here is my way to see it with the following arrays that are clearly in a bijective correspondence with the binary operations.

A $5 \times 5$ array of a commutative operation has this form:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
&a&b&c&d&e\\ \hline
a&s_1&r_1&r_2&r_3&r_4\\
b&r_1&s_2&r_5&r_6&r_7\\
c&r_2&r_5&s_3&r_8&r_{9}\\
d&r_3&r_6&r_8&s_4&r_{10}\\
e&r_4&r_7&r_9&r_{10}&s_5\\
\end{array}
$$

where we are free to place, for each of the 15 "sites" $r_1,\cdots r_{10}$ and $s_1,\cdots s_5$, one of the five elements $a,b,c,d,e$, giving rise to your solution $5^{15}$.

The solution given by the book looks to forget the diagonal choices.

Edit: I just saw a nice general answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2353150).

Comment: See [here](http://oeis.org/A023813) for the corresponding AOIS sequence. About the number of _associative_ laws, see [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/105438)